# How to replace the following pattern in php

Tags: php, regex, email

I just want to replace values (probably hexadecimal) that starts with (%...) in the following string.

```
$string = 'hello@example.com%0A%0a%0B%0C%0F%0f%AA';
```

and the expected out put is, hello@example.com.

How can I do this? I'm using `preg_replace` but failing with regex pattern.

Comment: lets hope your not harvesting email addresses for sapm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$string = preg_replace('/%[a-fA-F0-9]{2}/', '', $string);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to extract an email from such strings, there's also a solution without regex:

```
$string = substr($string, 0, strpos($string, '%'));
```